# Airflow: How to unpause DAG from python script

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

I'm creating a python script to generate DAGs (generate a new python file with the DAG specifications) from templates. It all works fine, except that I need the DAG to be be generated as unpaused.

I've searched and tried to run shell commands in the script like this:

```
bash_command1 = 'airflow list_dags'

bash_command2 = 'airflow trigger_dag ' + str(DAG_ID)

bash_command3 = 'airflow list_tasks ' + str(DAG_ID)

bash_command4 = 'airflow unpause '+ str(DAG_ID)

subprocess.call(bash_command1.split())
subprocess.call(bash_command2.split())
subprocess.call(bash_command3.split())
subprocess.call(bash_command4.split())
```

But every time I create a new DAG it is shown as paused in the web UI. 
By the research I´ve made, the command `airflow unpause <dag_id>` should solve the problem, but when the script executes it, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/airflow", line 28, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/cubo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 303, in unpause
    set_is_paused(False, args, dag)
  File "/home/cubo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site- packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 312, in set_is_paused
    dm.is_paused = is_paused
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_paused'
```

But when I execute the same `airflow unpause <dag_id>` command in the terminal it works fine, and it prints:

```
Dag: <DAG: DAG_ID>, paused: False
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow (1.8 and newer) [pauses new dags by default](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md). If you want all DAGs to be unpaused at creation, you can override the Airflow config to retain the prior behavior of unpausing at creation.

[Here's the link](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/set-config.html) that walks you through setting configuration options. You want to set a core configuration setting: dags_are_paused_at_creation to False.

We use the environment variable approach on my team.